# can I add to a language model a prompt with output example?

Tags: transformer, gpt, fine-tuning, prompt

I want to finetune GPT2 to extract relevant data from a given text. So for (a trivial) example, given the text "*the car was manufactured in X, can reach Y km/h, and has Z horse powers*", my desired output would be *manufacturer: `X`, max speed:`Y`, horsepowers:`Z`*.

I don't have a lot of labeled data, so I thought it would be reasonable to take every training sample and add to it a prefix than contains an actual example. That is - Instead of providing the model with the text

> INPUT: a well-known brand, the new `X`, can reach `Y` km/h, and has `Z` horsepower
>
> OUTPUT:

and expect the model to understand how to fill in the details, I would provide a longer prompt that contains an actual example like

> INPUT: the new `BMW` can reach up to `200` kmh. Even though the previous model disappointed the users, the brand-new one rocks a `thousand` engine horsepower
>
> OUTPUT: Manufacturer: `BMW`, Max Speed: `200`, Horse Powers: `thousand`
>
> INPUT: though is mostly considered an outdated version of the cls200, the new `Mercedes` has the capabilities of reaching up to 100kmh in turns and `300`kmh overall
>
> OUTPUT:

Is this considered a common way of engineering the prompt? Do notice that the first provided example is the same for every training sample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to finetune GPT2 to extract relevant data from a given text. For your example, you could add a prompt that looks for a **manufacturer**, **max speed**, and **horsepower**, and then provide an output example that includes that information.

It is possible to add a prefix to every training sample that contains an actual example. *This could help the model learn from data that has fewer labels*.

> `INPUT`: though is mostly considered an outdated version of the `cls 200`, the new Mercedes has the capabilities of reaching up to `100kmh` in turns and `300kmh` overall?
> The `OUTPUT` would be the capabilities of the new Mercedes, including its max speed and ability to handle turns.

Yes, this is considered a common way of engineering the prompt.

> Providing the `same` example for every training sample also help the
> model learn from data that has fewer labels.